# error "init terminating in do_boot" in chicago boss

Tags: erlang, erlangweb, chicagoboss

I just tried "make" in Chicago Boss(Erlang web framework) dir and failed
with error

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{make,all,[]},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}
```

What is wrong? What should I do?

My environment is Ubuntu 10.04, Erlang R13B03.

Comment: well that was not make alone, you've attempted to run the server after make went okay (at least that was my scenario to get the same error and land here after some googling)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error warns you that the function `make:all()` doesn't exist or couldn't be found. Given the `make:all()` function is part of the standard library shipped with Erlang and that you're on Ubuntu, I have to ask if you're using the default install of the language on there.

You have to know that Ubuntu strips down Erlang to the strict minimum required to run CouchDB on the live CD. There are other packages you need to install for it to work if that's your case — or otherwise just install from source, which is usually what I do.

Comment: I have default install of Erlang and I thought Chicago Boss should work out of the box.

Comment: It should work out of the box Erlang is usually shipped in. Ubuntu takes that box, tears it to pieces and hands you only the bottom of it.

Comment: To be fair that's not actually Ubuntu's fault directly.  That's more likely Debian's fault.

Comment: And how can I solve this problem? Chicago Boss seems so pretty and I want to try this, but I can't. =(

Comment: Install from source or get the additional packages